# Explain what TraitCollectionDidChange/UITraitCollection is in simple terms?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have the following code:

```swift
public override void TraitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection)
{
    base.TraitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    ...
}
```

What does `base.TraitCollectionDidChange()` do?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitenvironment/1623516-traitcollectiondidchange

Answer (score 0):

This methods will be called when your size class change. So you can adapt your layout :)

Have you heard about size class ?

Size class are an apple abstraction to define a size device.

For example to Iphone X have, that values :

**For Portrait :**
 - Compact width, regular height

**For Landscape :**
 - Compact width, compact height

With TraitCollection you can identify when this classes changes, for example from Portrait to Landscape, with this information you can update your layout.

**Here an tutorial:**
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-detect-when-your-size-class-changes

**Here an tutorial about size class:**
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/